# Is there a way to have alternating column groups have different background colors in SQL Reporting Services?

Tags: sql, ssrs-2008

I have a Report I'm designing in SQL Reporting Services that has column grouping.  Is there a way to specify that each column group should be an alternating color?  For example, I'd like column group one have a white background, column group 2 to have a blue background, column group 3 to be back to white, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with an expression in the *Background Color* properties.  You reference the dataset that you are using and use the modulus function

`=IIF(RowNumber("ResponseTime") Mod 2= 0, "Wheat", "FloralWhite")` 
In the above sample my dataset is *ResponseTime* and I am saying that when it is an even row, or grouping in your case, then the background color should beb Wheat, otherwise it should be FloralWhite.

Hope this helps